# Rails Javascript parsing using array from Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am doing Ajax Call from View, then controller is fetching data from DB into an Array, now this array value I want to pass to JavaScript, so that I can update data in a table with different id's

Controller code:

```
def AjaxView
 @var1 = Var.find(:all,:conditions => { :varname=> "one" },:select=> (params[:col]))
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js 
  end
end
```

AjaxView.js.erb code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#test").text("valuetoupdate");
  });
```

Now when I run this code it successfully update "valuetoupdate" at id =test in view page.
Instead of this I want to update all values one by one from array @var1.

I searched more and realized that array @var1 generated in Controller will automatically get transferred to AjaxView.js.erb file. Now I have to iterate over all values, but this code doesn't work in JavaScript file:

```
<% for var in @var1 %>
$("#3").text(var);
<% end %>
```

it gives blank response

Comment: You are missing the block for `format.js`. Also, please post your javascript so far that actually does the ajax call.

Comment: @Ben, javascript I added above works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, the javascript you posted works fine, but it's not an ajax call. Where is the code for your ajax call?

Comment: <li><%= link_to "Link", 
        {:action => "AjaxView",:col => "colname"},
        :update =>  "Ajaxcall",
        :remote => true %></li>

Comment: <tr>
<td id="test" style="height:25px">test</td>
<% end %>
</tr>
<tr>

Comment: Amit, you haven't provided enough information to give a complete answer.  To answer your question, we'll need some idea what you're getting back from your `Var.find(:all)` call, and what you want to show up in the `#test` td.  Are you trying to collect all the results and add them to the same element?  What's your goal?  And please update the question with this information so it will be easier for other viewers to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys,

I am able to resolve my issue, in following manner,
I moved away from for loop implementation, instead start using if else condition,

```
   <% if @var.to_s == 'valuetoupdate' %>
    { }
   <% elsif @var.to_s == 'valuetoupdate1' %>
    {}
```

And it worked fine for me.